# How to make comments in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments, haml

I've found some answers to generate commented HTML code with HAML :

```
/
  This is actually an HTML comment and not an HAML comment
```

But it's not what I want.
Indeed, I'm searching for a way to make a line comment in HAML like `//` in JavaScript or `#` in Ruby without delete the line and have to re-add it later.

So is there a way to do that in HAML, and how to do this if it's possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As nobody answered me (I'm very sad !), I didn't stop to search a method to make a comment in HAML file for Ruby, and I found something interesting :
Just declare a line as Ruby code (with `-`) and add your comment in Ruby !

Example:

```rb
%p= "Paragraph"
- # This is a comment in an HAML file and won't be interpreted, yay !
```

Comment: https://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#haml-comments-- (as another way to do it).